# Querys MYSQL PERTENCE

Tags: mysql, sql

Preciso fazer um `query` no `mysql`, dentro do `WHERE` preciso que está contendo o `COD_IDENT` dentro de um grupo. Ou seja:

```
COD_IDENT 
5
6
7
```

A minha `query` precisa retornar todos os resultados onde `COD_IDENT` seja igual a `5,6,7`

Eu tentei fazer utilizando `in` porém ele retorna apenas um resultado. NA verdade era pra voltar dois.

Eu fiz desta maneira:

```
SELECT COD_IDENT_REUNI, COD_IDENT_SALAX 
  FROM tbl_REUNIOES WHERE COD_IDENT_EMPRE = 'ibhr' and COD_IDENT_SALAX in
    (SELECT COD_IDENT_SALAX, max(DAT_IDENT_REUNI) 
      FROM tbl_REUNIOES WHERE COD_IDENT_EMPRE = 'ibhr' GROUP BY (COD_IDENT_SALAX))
```

Comment: Renan, você poderia adicionar mais detalhes sobre sua dúvida? As outras tabelas, quais a relações e etc. Fica mais fácil de te ajudar. Basicamente você quer um IN de valores distintos, o que poderia ser resolvido com `SELECT DISTINCT COD_IDENT FROM tbl_IDENTIFICACAO WHERE FLG_STATUS = 'S' `, mas poste mais informações, para facilitar na ajuda. [DISTINCT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/distinct-optimization.html)

Comment: @FernandoA.W. O que preciso está tudo em uma so tabela, porque seguinte nesta tabela existe varias REUNIÕES, e CADA REUNIÃO é DE UMA SALA preciso pegar a reunião mais recente de cada sala.  Suponhamos temos 4 salas, e cada salas teve 10 reuniões, preciso pegar a mais com a data maior.

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta

Comment: Veja se atende seu problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Renan, seu `IN` não vai funcionar porque você está passando mais de um parâmetro para ele, veja a documentação [IN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html).

Se bem entendi, você pode resolver seu problema com uma `SubQuery`, desta forma:

```
SELECT   A.COD_IDENT_REUNI, B.MAX_COD_IDENT_REUNI
  FROM   TBL_REUNIOES A, (  SELECT   COD_IDENT_SALAX, MAX (DAT_IDENT_REUNI) MAX_COD_IDENT_REUNI
                              FROM   TBL_REUNIOES
                             WHERE   COD_IDENT_EMPRE = 'ibhr'
                          GROUP BY   (COD_IDENT_SALAX)) B
 WHERE   A.COD_IDENT_REUNI = B.MAX_COD_IDENT_REUNI AND A.COD_IDENT_EMPRE = 'ibhr'
```

Existem outros meios, mas esta forma atende seu problema.

Comment: Ele não retornou o que preciso, na verdade nao retornou nada.

Comment: Renan, posta um exemplo da sua tabela, para que eu possa simular aqui.

Comment: OPs na verdade so o seu SELECT de dentro resolveu meu problema

Comment: Perfeito.... =)